# Hide debug files from project tab on Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a setting to hide debug files from project tab on Android Studio? These files were not visible on previous versions and I don't see any advantage on have them.

[image]

Comment: You might be happier with the Project view. You appear to be using the Android view. This is controlled by the drop-down above the tree.

Comment: I am very familiar with the project view. However, my goal was to hide debug files from Android view, as they were introduced in the latest version and are pretty useless.